# R package mrmre score calculation and extraction

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm using an R package called mRMRe to help me do some quick feature selection, but I found that the document of this package is so confusing.

my dataset has about 400 columns/features, and the last column is a binary outcome.

basically, I calculate the MRMR score like this:

```
tmp.step4 <- mRMR.classic( "mRMRe.Filter", 
                           data = myDataset , 
                           feature_count = featureCount( myDataset ) - 1, 
                           target_indices = 400 )
```

Since I don't know how many features I really need, I want to calculate the MRMR score of each feature and I can do stepwise variable elimination based on the score.

I retrieve the MRMR calculation result like this:

```
scores( tmp.step4 )
solutions( tmp.step4 )
```

I can see that the output of the solution function is a list of numeric values, which, I assume, is the index of my column/feature number. The output function of the scores function is a sorted numeric vector, but I don't think this is directly correspondent to my features (e.g. one to one projection).

**my question is really simple:**

how can I get the score to pair up with the feature name?
such as:
feature.1 : 0.111
feature.2 : 0.222
feature.3 : 0.333
...

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

after some digging up work, I think I got it...

the score needs to be paired with the solution, which gives an ordered column index of my dataset. Then, the score can be mapped accordingly.

Comment: could you please explain in more detail how you achieved that?